# Print NSImage in Correct Size

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

I am trying to print an NSImage but am having trouble getting it to be to proper size. I want the NSImage to be printed as a 4"x6" photo on any paper large enough. Here's the code I have now.

```
var printView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 72*4, height: 72*6))
var printInfo = NSPrintInfo()

printInfo.paperSize = NSSize(width: 72*4, height: 72*6)
printInfo.bottomMargin = 10
printInfo.topMargin = 10
printInfo.leftMargin = 10
printInfo.rightMargin = 10

printView.image = generateImage()
let printOp = NSPrintOperation(view: printView, printInfo: printInfo)
printOp.run()
```

Comment: Unless you spell it, nobody knows what your 'trouble' is.

Comment: It appears to be printing the image scaled to whatever size the paper is instead of being a fixed size

Comment: What settings are you using in the print dialog? There is a setting that scales the output to the page size. Is that set by any chance?

Comment: You can't change the size of the paper in code. The size of the paper in the printer won't change. What are `printInfo.horizontalPagination` and `printInfo.verticalPagination`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to fix my problem

```
var printView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 72*4, height: 72*6))
var printInfo = NSPrintInfo()

printInfo.bottomMargin = 0
printInfo.topMargin = 0
printInfo.leftMargin = 0
printInfo.rightMargin = 0

printView.image = generateImage()
let printOp = NSPrintOperation(view: printView, printInfo: printInfo)
printOp.run()
```